# Generate list of years to be used as link based on table in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database, which contains a list of dates, I would like to generate the each year once, so as to be used as a link.  How can this be done?
This  is my work so far:

```
function generate_years($sql) {
include 'connect.php';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
    $formatted_date = $date->format('Y');
    echo "<a href='races.php?year=".$formatted_date."'><button>".$formatted_date."</button></a>";
}
}

 <?php generate_years("SELECT date FROM races ORDER BY date"); ?>
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2016'><button>2016</button></a>
<a href='races.php?year=2016'><button>2016</button></a>
```

Whereas I would like each year to be echoed only once like this:

```
<a href='races.php?year=2015'><button>2015</button></a>
    <a href='races.php?year=2016'><button>2016</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the SQL to:

```
<?php generate_years("SELECT year(date) FROM races GROUP BY year(date)
ORDER BY date"); ?>
```

**Explanation:**

`GROUP BY year(date)`: Group date field by `year`.

This way, you will get only one record per year.

Comment: Thanks :) needed to change the function slightly to: function generate_years($sql) {
 include 'connect.php';
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0);
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<a href='races.php?year=".$row['year(date)']."'><button>".$row['year(date)']."</button></a>\n";
 }
}